# Applying from Ghana or Benin Republic to the US as No available dates in Nigeria

Tags: visas, usa, nigerian-citizens

Good day,

I have a question that bothers me I want to ask.
I will be visiting a Neighboring country, which happens to be either Ghana or the Benin Republic. Now I wanted to try out applying for US visas at the US embassy in Accra or Cotonou. Now here is what I want to know. I saw this

[image: 2222.png]

What I want to know is this
I am applying as a third-country national to either of the countries as we currently do not have available dates until 2024 in Nigeria, Can I at the same time visit either of them to apply for US visas there? Owning to the fact I am not a Resident there, neither am I a Citizen? We Enjoy the Visa-free movement, Can this be acceptable to go to Ghana and apply for US Visas? I saw someplace that I could apply for US Tourist visas from the Dominican Republic even if I am no Resident permit holder as well. Since I cannot go that far at this point, I chose a place closer. Can this suffice too?

Kindly advice.

Comment: It's legal for you to apply in Ghana but the chances of getting one are very small.  Take a look at https://gh.usembassy.gov/visas/.  Tourist visa applications are severely limited and as a non-resident you'll probably be at the bottom of the pile.